# Avete il mio libro o Hai il mio libro?

Tags: grammar, verbs, agreement

Sono da Mèxico e ho trovato che *`Avete il mio libro?`* si traduce come *`¿Tienes mi libro?`*.

*`Tienes`* è il verbo *`Tener`* coniugato per la seconda persona del singolare in spagnolo e  *`Tienes`*  significa *`Hai`* in italiano; ma so anche che *`Avete`*   è il verbo *`Avere`* coniugato per la seconda persona del plurale.

La mia domanda è: si deve usare `Hai` o `Avete` nella domanda e perché?

[Qui](http://tatoeba.org/spa/sentences/show/2422899) è dove ho incontrato questo.

Comment: Non riesco ad aprire il tuo link, prova a controllare

Comment: @Darko Try again.

Comment: Come ti scrivo nella risposta, dipende dal contesto. In che testo hai trovato la frase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si usa la seconda persona singolare

```
Hai il mio libro?
```

Ed è corretto in generale, eccetto per i seguenti casi.

A volte quando si parla ad una persona più importante, in segno di rispetto, "si da del lei" (ovvero ci si riferisce alla persona con la terza persona singolare) o "si da del voi" (e quindi con la seconda persona plurale). Quindi se la domanda che hai trovato è riferita ad una persona verso cui chi chiede deve rispetto, copre un grado inferiore (come uno studente ad un professore, ad esempio) è possibile che tu abbia trovato

```
Avete il mio libro?
```

o anche

```
Ha il mio libro?
```

rispettivamente in seconda persona plurale e terza singolare.

Quindi in generale è corretto il primo caso, ma su fatto che tu abbia trovato `Avete`, dipende da chi chiede la domanda e chi risponde

Comment: Avete si usa anche se la domanda è rivolta a più di una persona. Ad esempio chiedi a 2 amici: "Avete il mio libro?" Oppure se è rivolta a un gruppo di persone senza rivolgersi a qualcuno in particolare.

Answer (score 4):

Nei tempi passati, la forma di cortesia prevalente in italiano era il “voi”, cioè la seconda persona plurale. La forma è ancora viva nell'Italia meridionale, specialmente a Napoli, dove è normale che la gente si rivolga a una persona che non conosce con il “voi”.

La forma di cortesia più comune, ormai, è il “lei” (con la terza persona singolare).

Tuttavia è piuttosto comune usare il “voi” in modo impersonale. Se vado in una libreria in cerca di un titolo, chiederò

> Avete un'edizione pregiata dei “Promessi Sposi” per un regalo?

perché mi sto rivolgendo al personale della libreria. Se invece vado dal salumiere e so che la persona dietro al banco è il proprietario, chiederò

> Ha salame di Felino?

ma non sarebbe strano domandare anche in questo caso

> Avete salame di Felino?

(nota per gli stranieri: non si tratta di salame di gatto, ma del famoso salame di suino che si produce nei dintorni di Felino, provincia di Parma).

In mancanza di contesto è difficile dire come tradurre la frase. Potrebbe essere uno che si rivolge a un ufficio oggetti smarriti e quindi adopera “avete” impersonale; oppure la domanda potrebbe essere rivolta agli occupanti di una stanza che forse hanno il mio libro.