# Perché "voi" è usato quando si parla con solo una persona?

Tags: pronouns, plural

Quando parlo con persone italiane è normale io dire "Grazie mille" e loro rispondono "Grazie a voi" o soltanto "a voi" anche quando io sono solo. Mi piacerebbe di sapere perché questo succede.

Comment: Hai provato a cercare su [un dizionario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/voi/), per cominciare?

Comment: Per curiosità, quanto spesso? Dalle mie parti dare del voi mi sembra piuttosto in disuso; a me non lo darebbero comunque vista la relativamente giovane età, mi capita spesso di trattare con coetanei o comunque con gente più "matura", ma onestamente non ricordo di averlo sentito dare neanche a persone più anziane di me, quindi *immagino* sia piuttosto raro.

Comment: Sono gioavane anche e ho sentito molte volte, ho chiesto perché ho imparato che voi é per due o piu persone. I luogi che ho piu sentito normalmente erano negozi, stazioni ferroviari e qualche volte in ristoranti

Comment: @Enthusiast related question: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/avete-il-mio-libro-o-hai-il-mio-libro

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Thanks, that really put a light on

Comment: My bet is that you have met people from the Campania region, of which Naples is the capital city. In Campania the use of _Voi_ instead of _Lei_ (the standard _you_ of formal speech) is commonplace.

Comment: Walter Tross: It is not only Campania, but South Italy in general. It is clearly an influence from the French language due to the dominance of the Borboni during the Regno delle Due Sicilie. In French  _vous_ is used to show respect (similarly to the italian more common _lei_)

Comment: @RiccardoI., as far as my experience goes, the _Voi_ is much more in use in Campania than elsewhere in the south. If you have different data, I will be happy to read it. Regarding the influence from French, could you cite a source?

Comment: @RiccardoI.: Not only in French, this form of respect exists also in Spanish ("vos") and in Catalan ("vós").

Comment: It's in disuse in Spanish (in Spain), but it's already used in Catalan (it's in decaying use, however).

Comment: @Charo vos is very used in Spain and Argentina

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: I mean the pronoun "vos" or "Vos" (conjugated as second-person plural if accompanied with a verb) to address one person in a polite way: this use has disappeared in nowadays Spanish from Spain. I know it's used in Argentina, but it's used instead of the pronoun "tú" and not as a courtesy form.

Comment: Well, I have seen it in South Italy also but I've spent most of the time in Veneto and a little bit in Lombardia and they did say "voi" a lot

Comment: @WalterTross: I don't have references for the French influence and that's the reason this is a comment and not an answer. Regarding the south in general I can only tell from having spent my childhood holidays in Puglia and Calabria. The use of _Chi faciti, duve annati_ in Calabrian dialect is very common as well as the use of _Voi_ in Puglia where talking to a person not known or addressing respectfully to someone.

Comment: @RiccardoI., my experience is that, if, e.g., you go alone to a (non-low-class, to exclude dialect) restaurant in Campania, you are much more likely to be addressed with _Voi_ (instead of _Lei_) than in any other region. This is not in contrast with what you say - but, of course, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si chiamano allocutivi di cortesia. Per rivolgersi ad altre persone si usano pronomi a seconda del contesto o dell'età (un tempo anche dell'importanza sociale).

Il Lei e il Voi si utilizzano ora generalmente in contesti formali o con persone più anziane:

[Allocutivi di cortesia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-allocutivi_(La_grammatica_italiana)/)

Nel corso della storia il  loro significato ed il loro utilizzo sono però cambiati spesso:

[Breve storia del tu, del Lei e del voi](http://www.alfacert.unibo.it/resources/progetti/corsi_moduli/ita_b1/moduli/schede/files/a2/m02p08_brevestoria.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sono d'accordo con Walter Villa e con la "Breve Storia" (come ho indicato). Aggiungo che le mie cugine in Toscana (ora intorno ai 70 anni) hanno dato del Voi alla nostra nonna, fino alla sua morte, mentre io (che vivevo a Genova) le ho sempre dato del tu. In Toscana il Voi è andato avanti per molto tempo. 
Una curiosità: se il Lei sembrava sotto il "regime" poco italiano, il Voi lo è ancora di meno: è una chiara abitudine inglese, parlato allora da un circa un terzo del mondo. Ora anche di più. Insomma il Voi non è per niente antico.  Sono semmai quelli che non lo usano che sono sempre di meno ...

Comment: Credo proprio che il "Voi" dato in inglese sia sempre il Tu (o il Voi "proprio" per parlare a più persone). O mi sto sbagliando di grosso? Penso ti sia confuso/confusa anche con "Sono semmai quelli che non lo usano che sono sempre di meno", forse volevi dire "[...] sono sempre di più", che sarebbe quello che capisco dal "Semmai" e dalla frase precedente?

Comment: @kos, in inglese ci si dà sempre del _Voi_ (solo dal punto di vista linguistico, naturalmente), perché il _tu_ ([_thou_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou)) è caduto in disuso. Quanto al _Voi_ italiano, non mi risulta che derivi da quello inglese. L'uso del plurale come forma di cortesia è semplicemente molto diffuso.

Comment: @WalterTross Beh mi sbagliavo di grosso allora, ho sempre creduto fosse l'esatto contrario. Grazie

Comment: @kos Di niente. Per quanto riguarda la diffusione e la storia del plurale come forma di cortesia, nella pagina Wikipedia sul [_thou_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou) c'è il link alla pagina sulla [_T-V distinction_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T–V_distinction) (che riporto qui per comodità), anche raggiungibile come "versione inglese" della pagina sulla [allocuzione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocuzione).

Answer (score 0):

È in disuso. In passato, soprattutto nel sud Italia (meridione) ma non solo, veniva usato al posto di "Lei" quando si parlava con persone ritenute importanti o di alto rango a volte anche con familiari stretti.